# Auto Class Generators for RESTful services

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

**What I have,**
   I have a DB schema with 10 tables and basic relationships (one to one, one to many ) between the tables.

**What I need,**
   I need to create webservices to access this DB Data (Lets ignore the business logic layer as of now) with basic CRUD operations

**What I know,**
   I know we have JPA to generate entities, and jackson to map between json and POJO classes.

Now is there a tool which takes the DB Schema as input and generates the RESTful service classes, JPA entities with jackson annotations

**Note:**
 We can use Spring to achieve most of it.  But I dont want to use Spring or any J2EE framework for various other reasons.

Comment: Is creating JPA entities a requirement? Could you use something like JOOQ?

Comment: I also had pretty much the same requirements and couldnt find anything that solved this. So I developed my own solution using CodeModel. It takes some time to learn as the documentation is hard to find. However using CodeModel really helps you understand programming in Java in general and you get exactly what you want as an end result. a win win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) is the Best and the easiest.
Just right click on your web project and click on new as the picture

[image]

and if you want to create restfull web services from entity classes
Just right click on your entity classes package and click on new

[image]

[Getting Started with RESTful Web Services](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/)?
It's a tool that allows you, amongst many other things, to generate JPA entities from table and generate REST services as well (I've personally tested the JPA entities generation only). It doesn't rely on any framework, only on Java EE standard such as JPA and JAX-RS.

After creating the new project you have to call

```
 jpa-generate-entities-from-table
```

to generate the entities (JPA classes) and then

```
rest-generate-endpoints-from-entities
```

to generate the REST endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think the IDE which you are using or you have option to use that is very important.

**For MyEclipse**

If you have option to use **MyEclipse** then you can expose JPA Entities via REST Web Services very easily without installing any plugins. Here is the link 
[Exposing JPA Entities via REST Web Services](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/ws/exposing-jpa-entities-via-rest-web-services/)

**Texo**

You can also go for [Texo](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Texo) if you think that is suitable for you

or if you are using Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.2) or later then 
[Oracle® Fusion Middleware Solutions](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/restful_jpa.htm#TLADG1159) will be a good choice