# REST - populate endpoint automatically

Tags: api, rest, express

So i've been working on a REST api using express amd got most of the basics done. The current api I have does some simple GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and was able to populate a small client demo in both webapp and ios app.

But now I am trying to figure something out
**Example:**

```
/api/tvshow/
```

Returns a tv show object like:

```
[{
    "Title": "Show title",
    "Channel": "ABC",
    "Started": "04/04/2012",
    "Ended": "08/07/2015"
}]
```

Would it be possible to get 2 endpoints like

```
/api/tvshow/channels/
```

To get all channels in it's own list

```
/api/tvshow/channels/:channelName
```

To get all shows that are running on that channel all based from the main `/api/tvshows/`

Basically I would like for these to be populated automatically based on the current entries in the api.
Or would something like manually adding all these be better?

Comment: What language do you use? Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299248/auto-class-generators-for-restful-services or https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/ws/exposing-jpa-entities-via-rest-web-services/ ?

Comment: Ahh sorry it wasn't really clear but I use Node, Javascript and the Express framework.